# hadoop-datanode is not running

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and did installation hadoop-2.7.3.Also completed all the steps for installation.however my datanode is not running after ran the command start-all.sh.
So my doubt is **what action need to take if i'm rerunning the command hadoop namenode -format** ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

If your datanode is not running then there could be many prob. 
Either the directory you set in hdfs-site.xml file is not right or the cluster id in which you datanode is present doesn't match the cluster id with your namenode and many more.

Do the following and comment or edit your question after running the commands with the output attached..

1. Check whether the directory are set properly in **hdfs-site.xml** (syntax /home/yourComputerName/datanode or namenode)
2. **Delete all the directory** (namenode, datanode, tmp)
3. Format the namenode again.. (**hadoop namenode -format**)
4. Start all the daemons(services) ("**start-all.sh**") and use "**jps**" to check weather all daemons are working or not (there should be six daemons)
5. If still problem exist then try command "**hadoop datanode**" after start-all.sh and paste the error while editing the question. 
   After that i will help you further.

Thanks